# Tooltip tools that play nice with Aspnet and Ajax

Tags: asp.net, css, ajax, tooltip

I am a tech writer and am working in visual studio creating tooltips for an ERP site. Originally we were using the Jquery tools from flow player http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/form.html but these did not agree with our asp elements. Specifically the drop down and check boxes. It also caused odd display features with our buttons. On one page the display looked great until an autogenerate button was pushed. Then, all of the formatting went away.

So my question is, is there something else that's free that can allow me to style my tooltips and work well with ajax? Thanks for any and all help. I am really new to this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

We've used [qtip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/), and it works great.  But it's an ASP.NET MVC site, so ymmv.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will look into it, though all of our pages are webforms so it may have the same result as the flowplayer tools.